# Loading zipped data feeds into Google App Engine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm building an app using django-nonrel and currently have some crons that pull data dumps from various sources, unzip them in a temp directory and parse them and load them into the datastore on dev.

How can you fetch and unzip data dumps on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can fetch via HTTP and unzip in-memory.